# Publishing while working from home independently, what affiliation to give?

Tags: independent-researcher, affiliation

Currently I do not belong to any institution and work from home.

Now can I put the name of the last university I attended  in place of affiliation in a journal paper?

I have masters degree from Linkoping University, Sweden. Do I need to ask permission in this case ?

Regards,
Umair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should not put any institution as your affiliation unless you are currently based there, or did the work while you were based there. In this case, unless you did the research while at Linkoping, you should **not** give Linkoping as your affiliation.

See, for example, [this discussion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59327/what-affiliation-to-put-for-amateur-scientist-who-is-an-alumni-out-of-school-for?rq=1).

If it helps, it's worth remembering that the "affiliation" is in many ways an "address" - it evolved out of simply giving an address at which you could be contacted, and some journals still refer to it this way. It's not unknown in some fields for independent researchers to give their home address, but it's perhaps more common just to say "independent".

If you have no current affiliation, you can simply say "Independent researcher", or similar, and leave it at that (adding an email address is good, if not asked for elsewhere in the paper).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can ask, if you still have contacts there, to become an adjunct/visiting researcher, getting a proper affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

You should leave it blank, or provide the name of your independent business (if you have one).