# Where and how to publish research paper as a non-academic independent researcher

Tags: journals, independent-researcher, publishability

I am an independent researcher with out a PhD and because of my curiosity in science in my free time I carries out some minor experiments. Using those experimental data I wrote a paper and I want to publish it as a research article.

My first question; Is there any journal available where an independent researcher can publish his/her work?

As I believe no such journals are available I thought of sending my articles to other peer reviewed journals?

But the problem is how will I address my author information

[In this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3477468/) author information is given like this

```
Nora D. Volkow,1,2 Gene-Jack Wang,3 Joanna S. Fowler,3 and Dardo Tomasi2

1National Institute on Drug Abuse (NIDA), National Institutes of Health, Bethesda, Maryland 20892
2National Institute on Alcohol Abuse and Alcoholism (NIAAA), National Institutes of Health, Bethesda, Maryland 20892
3Medical Department, Brookhaven National Laboratory, Upton, New York 11973
Nora D. Volkow: vog.hin.adin@woklovn
```

As I am an independent researcher who is not working in the similar field of my research work, how should I give my author information?

Do I give my current employment details as author information

```
Eka,
Supervisor,
XYZ company
```

or my last school details

```
Eka,
University of Earth
```

Comment: *Is there any journal available where an independent researcher can publish his/her work? As I believe no such journals are available I thought of sending my articles to other peer reviewed journals?* – I fail to make sense of these sentences. If there were no peer-reviewed journals that allow publications from independent researchers, there are no “other peer reviewed journals” to send your article to.

Answer (score 8):

On the first question, you can and should submit to "normal" journals. There is no special publication track you have to use. Independent non-academic researchers are unusual in some fields but quite common in others,

On the second question, see [this discussion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62017/publishing-while-working-from-home-independently-what-affiliation-to-give/62019#62019) - in short, you can give your own address, your company (if they're happy with this - ask), or just something like "independent researcher". Do *not* give a university you attended in the past, as this implies you carried out the work there and could be seen as misleading.